# How to switch visual studio 2010 safe mode to 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to open up Visual Studio in safe mode by typing in `devenv /SafeMode` in run however it only opens up the 2010 edition. How do I switch it so it opens the 2012 or 15 edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path to the corresponding Visual Studio executable. For VS 2012:

> "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /SafeMode